# how to convent a NSString * to a file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, csv

I have a NSString *csvData which contains the csv data and the format is correct.

In my program (the iPhone), there is a button. When the user click the button, the string will convent to the .csv file. However, I don't know how to convent the NSString to a CSV file. Does the objective C provides any build-in function or class can help me to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `NSFileManager` [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/) and especially the `- (BOOL)createFileAtPath:(NSString *)path contents:(NSData *)contents attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes`.

Best
–f

Comment: thank you for your reply. And I want to ask, where does the file store in the iPhone?

Comment: It stores the file at the path you hand over as the first parameter. You can get your documents directory like this:

`NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: thank you for your reply. I still have a problem, can you show the steps on how to open the file on the iPhone?

Comment: There are multiple ways. See the `NSString` class reference, for example:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:

Answer (score 2):

Read the NSString documentation ? It took me 10seconds :

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)useAuxiliaryFile encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I want to ask where does the file store in the iPhone?

Comment: @MarkSiu wherever you tell it to (as long as you have permission to write there).  That's the purpose of the `path` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To learn more about file paths on the iPhone, read [Files and File System](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW11) in the **iOS Application Programming Guide**.